# Set Maximum Allowed Panning Area

Tags: arcobjects, c#, visual-studio, wpf, arcgis-api-wpf

I'd like to fix the maximal area, in which the user can fly around. Now its possible for the user, to pan everywhere he wants to go. For e.g. to XMin: 216.2.

My map has got these "borders":

> - XMin: 674580.199070543
> - YMin: 241290.573962568
> - XMax: 691333.99095178
> - YMax: 254627.474078552

How can I specify that the user can only pan from XMin to XMax and from YMin to YMax.
I'm using ESRI API for WPF and C# in Visual Studio 2010.